# Finding unique values for a specific column in a group

Tags: r, dplyr, distinct

```
    ID<-(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3))   
    type<-(c("A1","A1","A1","A1","A1","A1","A1","B1"))  
    ag_id<-(c("A0001","A0001","A0001","A0001","A0001","A0001","A0001","B0001")) 
    Outcome<-(c("Aggressive","Aggressive","Aggressive","Aggressive","Aggressive","Aggressive","Aggressive","Balanced")) 
    bdate<-c("2012","2012","2012","2012","2012","2012","2012","2012")   
    sd_num<-(c("AIG0001","AIG0001","AIG0001","AIG0001","AIG0001","AIG0001","AIG0001","AIG0001"))  

    buy_pattern<-data.frame(ID,type,ag_id,Outcome,bdate,sd_num)




  #   > buy_pattern
  #     ID type ag_id    Outcome bdate  sd_num
  #   1  1   A1 A0001 Aggressive  2012 AIG0001
  #   2  1   A1 A0001 Aggressive  2012 AIG0001
  #   3  1   A1 A0001 Aggressive  2012 AIG0001
  #   4  1   A1 A0001 Aggressive  2012 AIG0001
  #   5  1   A1 A0001 Aggressive  2012 AIG0001
  #   6  1   A1 A0001 Aggressive  2012 AIG0001
  #   7  2   A1 A0001 Aggressive  2012 AIG0001
  #   8  3   B1 B0001   Balanced  2012 AIG0001
```

How can i find **unique values for ID column in a group**, I am able to accomplish it using `sqldf` in `distinctID` column

```
data<-sqldf("select count(distinct ID) as distinctID,count(type) as rowCount,type,ag_id,Outcome,bdate,sd_num from buy_pattern group by ag_id,Outcome,sd_num,bdate")


 # > data 
 # distinctID rowCount type ag_id    Outcome bdate  sd_num
 # 1          2        7   A1 A0001 Aggressive  2012 AIG0001
 # 2          1        1   B1 B0001   Balanced  2012 AIG0001
```

On trying using length(unique(ID)) gives total row count instead of count in a specific group

```
    data<-buy_pattern %>% select(type,ag_id,Outcome,bdate,sd_num) %>% 
    group_by(type,ag_id,Outcome,sd_num,bdate) %>%    
    mutate(rowCount = n(),distinctID=length(unique(ID))) %>% 
    arrange(ag_id,Outcome,sd_num, desc(rowCount))  %>% 
    slice(1)     

 # > data

 #  distinctID rowCount type ag_id    Outcome bdate  sd_num
 #  1          3        7   A1 A0001 Aggressive  2012 AIG0001
 #  2          3        1   B1 B0001   Balanced  2012 AIG0001
```

Comment: We can use `n_distinct` The reason is that you didn't have `ID` in the `select`

Comment: `sapply(split(buy_pattern$ID, buy_pattern$Outcome), unique)`

Comment: or `tapply(buy_pattern$ID, buy_pattern$Outcome, unique)`  (depending on exactly what you define as your group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason is that 'ID' as an object is created in the global env as a `vector` and within the `dplyr` chain, the `select` didn't call the 'ID' resulting in 'ID' being taken from the global env.   The whole vector 'ID' would have 3 unique elements and it is not following the `group_by` step.  Basically, keeping the 'ID' within the `select` will solve the issue.  There is `n_distinct` to replace `length(unique(`

```
buy_pattern %>% 
      select(ID, type,ag_id,Outcome,bdate,sd_num) %>% # change here
      group_by(type,ag_id,Outcome,sd_num,bdate) %>%
      mutate(rowCount = n(),distinctID=length(unique(ID))) %>% 
      arrange(ag_id,Outcome,sd_num, desc(rowCount))  %>% 
      slice(1) 
# A tibble: 2 x 8
# Groups:   type, ag_id, Outcome, sd_num, bdate [2]
#     ID   type  ag_id    Outcome  bdate  sd_num rowCount distinctID
#   <dbl> <fctr> <fctr>     <fctr> <fctr>  <fctr>    <int>      <int>
#1     1     A1  A0001 Aggressive   2012 AIG0001        7          2
#2     3     B1  B0001   Balanced   2012 AIG0001        1          1
```

---

Instead of `mutate`, we can use `summarise`

```
buy_pattern %>%
     group_by(type, ag_id, Outcome, sd_num, bdate) %>%
     summarise(rowCount = n(), distinctID = n_distinct(ID))
```

Comment: Is there any difference between mutate and summarize in this example?

Comment: @Akki The difference is that `mutate` will have all the columns and then when you `slice` it will give the first row of that each group where as `summarise` will not give the 'ID' i.e.the columns that are specified in the group_by and the new summarized columns will be there in the output

Comment: Will summarise give performance advantage when running this example on 3.5 million rows?

Comment: @Akki With `mutate`, you are creating columns while `summarise` just summarises it.  So, there would be some increase in performance